# using where clause in laravel but it only returns one value instead of a set of values

Tags: php, laravel

`id=>0` gets me no data while `id=>1` gets me data having `id` `1`.
I want display all that have an id in the options box.

```
$companies = Company::where(['id'=>0])->get();
        $companies_dropdown = "<option selected disabled>Please select from below</option>";
        foreach($companies as $com){
            $companies_dropdown .= "<option value='".$com->id."'>".$com->name."</option>";
```

Comment: do you have selected IDs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your field 'id' in table company may only be containing integers
 so in this case you will fetching simply as :

```
$companies = Company::select('id', 'name')->get();
```

if your company table is containing id as null then :

```
$companies = Company::select('id', 'name')->whereNotNull('id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all the row that has an 'Id'

```
$companies = Company::whereNotNull('id')->get();
```

Comment: gives this error:strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: in which file and which line?

Comment: this one:$companies = Company::whereNotNull('id')->get();

Comment: can you please explain what are you trying to accomplish here in this code.
`$companies = Company::where(['id'=>0])->get();`

Comment: I simply want to get all rows from company table into options box

Comment: OK, first thing, my answer is a simple statement. there is no errors in that. It returns all the row which has its 'id' column filled (as you specified in the question) . if it returns an error, you better check your table structure (whether it has a column named 'id').
Second thing, the statement you tried `Company::where(['id'=>0])->get();` is wrong.

Comment: if I put Company::where(['id'=>1])->get(); It shows value of row whose Id is 1

Comment: Obviously column with id exists. Thats why its returning data. I want id 1 and greater than 1 where it returns equal to 1

Comment: if you want rows which id is grater that 1, this is how you do it. `Company::where(['id', '>=', 0])->get();` see the difference

Answer (score 0):

if you have selected IDs in your options box.

```
Company::whereBetween('id', array( $ids ))->get();
```